# Is it better to use multiple states or one state object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

If I had a functional component which required use and manipulation of multiple state items, and I had multiple states going for different things that arent directly related (such as game statistics and UI element states) would it be better performance (or practice) wise to do it like this:

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    username: 'JoeSchmoe200',
    points: 200,
    isHoveringOverItem: {item1: false, item2: false, item3: false},
    selectedItem: {item1: true, item2: false, item3: false}
})
```

(where everything held in state is in one object and set with one method), or like this:

```
const [username, setUsername] = React.useState('JoeSchmoe200')
const [points, setPoints] = React.useState(200)
const [isHoveringOverItem, setIsHoveringOverItem] = React.useState(
    {item1: false, item2: false, item3: false}
)
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = React.useState(
    {item1: true, item2: false, item3: false}
)
```

where each state is declared individually and set individually. I'm just trying to spark a conversation here to learn more about React.

What do you think about this performance-wise? Readability-wise? **Is it a matter of preference or is there an objective best practice?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prior to React 18, it was recommended to group state variables that were expected to change together. React used to batch state updates but only those directly within React events such as `onClick`, `onChange`, etc. and lifecycle methods such as `useEffect`. Multiple state updates within async methods e.g. `fetch()` weren't batched.

However with React 18, all state updates occurring together are automatically batched into a single render. This means it is okay to split the state into as many separate variables as you like.

Source: https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html#new-feature-automatic-batching

Still, it is a good practice IMO to keep related pieces together for better code readability. But state objects should be kept at a manageable size otherwise `useReducer()` should be used.

Comment: Can anyone explain why `useReducer` should be used over using useState for storing large objects like OP mentioned. I just want to understand from a javascript point of view.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word it better. I mean useReducer should be preferred where state updates are **complex** (nothing to do with object size). So if you feel your state changes follow some pattern that can be modeled as a state machine, then useReducer can help. @BARNOWL

Answer (score 7):

With React 18, state updates are automatically batched so you don't really need to mash everything together in a single state object. Read the section on Automatic Batching [here.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18.html) Knowing that, here are some tips I got from [This Article](https://oskari.io/blog/stop-react-global-state-part-1/)

- Keep your state as flat as possible. Nested objects are unruly to
  manage and can introduce re-rendering bugs.
- Not everything needs to
  be a state object.
- Use succinct and descriptive names.

Comment: This answer, helped me solve a bug :)