# React.js :: When displaying a list of items, what is the best way to track the status/state of each item?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

My React component displays a list of calendar appointment "attendees" and allows the user to resend or delete the invite. The list is fetched and loaded into an array `eventAttendees`. My question is how best to keep track of state when the user clicks resend or delete (and if there is an error when attempting one of these actions).  I am considering using a immutable Map to track the status so I can display "resending..." or "deleting...", but I'm not sure if this is a best practice or considered an anti-pattern.

For Example:

[image]

```
// Data
const [eventAttendees, setEventAttendees] = useState([]);

// UI updating flags with the eventAttendeeId as the key
const [eventAttendeeStatusMap, setEventAttendeeStatusMap] = useState(Map());
```

The Map value would contain an object with the following flags

```
{
  isResending: false,
  isDeleting: false,
  hasError: false,
  errorMsg: null,
}
```

And then when rendering each item (Invite), I would reference the Map to display things properly.

```
{eventAttendees.map(eventAttendee =>
    <Invite
        key={eventAttendee.eventAttendeeId}
        {...eventAttendee}
        {...eventAttendeeStatusMap.get(eventAttendee.eventAttendeeId)}
    />
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would deal with this at the Invite component level rather than storing everything in the parent.

The Invite component would have to handle the logic of resending and deleting.

Comment: Got it - would you then have separate flags setup like: const [idsResending, setIdsResending] = useState(false);

Comment: @Burton since you only have two possible status, yes it's fine. Otherway you could  store the status in only one state status = "resending" | "deleting" | ...other status

Comment: just as a follow up, is it considered an anti pattern to have an object as a state variable?  In other words, if I wanted a single state variable to contain several flags, is it best separate those out into separate const variables or have a single object?

Comment: @Burton it... Depends ! [Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73300463/is-it-better-to-use-multiple-states-or-one-state-object-in-react)